# Android HorizontalScrollView content Stretch

Tags: java, android, android-xml, horizontalscrollview

I have a HorizontalScrollView with some buttons, I am trying to stretch these buttons to fill the whole width of the HorizontalScrollView so that they can appear organized and equally spaced between each others. Here is the Image which I have.
[image: HorizontalScrollView content Unstretched]

I want these 4 buttons to be stretched over the whole width! here is my code

```
    <HorizontalScrollView
    android:id="@+id/items_HorizontalBar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/vf"
    android:background="#80000000"
    android:fillViewport="true" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/rss"
            android:text="Light"
            android:textColor="@color/green_color"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/rss"
            android:text="Door"
            android:textColor="@color/green_color"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/rss"
            android:text="Alarms"
            android:textColor="@color/green_color"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/rss"
            android:text="Window"
            android:textColor="@color/green_color"
            android:textSize="20sp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For equal distributions, set the **weightSum** value of the parent, and assign **layout_weight** to its children.

For 4 equal sized buttons, add `android:weightSum="1"` to the LinearLayout. For each of the buttons set `android:layout_width="0dp"`, then add `android:layout_weight="0.25"`.

This is what occurs in the code but depending on the View, the *"Distribute Weights Evenly"* button in the Eclipse GUI can also help.

However, [HorizontalScrollView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/HorizontalScrollView.html) can only host one direct child, I wonder about the structure of this layout...

Comment: This is PERFECT! I knew that the answer was in android:layout_weight="0.25" but I didn't know how to make the total weight sum of the LinearLayout be 1 :D. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of messing with `LinearLayout` you should follow the correct solution that is setting the `HorizontalScrollView` (or Vertical) to **`FillViewPort`**.

**XML:**

```
android:fillViewport="true"
```

**Programmatically:**

```
hsv.setFillViewport(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

try making the container a horizontal scroll view. After that add in a table layout, and in each row of the table add in a horizontal linear layer. what will now happen instead, is that the scroll view will be stretched to fit the button size you set, and should scroll w/o you having to program a thing, and you should have effectively created a grid.
try something similar to this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<HorizontalScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/sc1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:scrollbars="horizontal" >

<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >



            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button1"
                android:layout_width="180dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button" />



            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button2"
                android:layout_width="180dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button" />



            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button3"
                android:layout_width="230dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button" />



            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button4"
                android:layout_width="233dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

Also perhaps you could wrap the horizontal scroll view in a vertical scroll view then you can scroll up/down, left/right and do as you need.